# Change paypal payments standard variable

Tags: paypal

I am using paypal payments standard, the shipping price is transferred as a product line (item variable) and therefore does not show in paypal as a postage amount. How can I change the shipping from item variable to shipping variable?

Answer (score 1):

The user is redirected to paypal, this happens here:

```
\Mage_Paypal_StandardController::redirectAction
```

The form which is used to sent the data to paypal is built here:

```
\Mage_Paypal_Block_Standard_Redirect
```

the fields are generated here:

```
\Mage_Paypal_Model_Standard::getStandardCheckoutFormFields
```

And with everything about paypal in magento, there exists no event you can use. So you have to rewrite at least one of the presented classes to achieve what you want and remove the shipping item and add the shipping amount.

Comment: have any idea about paypal multi currency?